# Change side that bootstrap-datepicker opens from?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm checking out [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and would like to customize it a little.  Is it possible for the calendar to open from the right side of the input box and right aligned with the input box?  Right now by default it always open left aligned with the input field.

The reason I need it to be right aligned is because I'm using it in a mobile app and with the input on the right half of the screen the calendar runs off the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try to specify over this setting "orientation"

```
 $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    orientation: "auto right"
});
```

http://bit.ly/1bj5HSD

Comment: That's a different datepicker library but thankd for the tip.  I think I'll use the one you linked to.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
$('#sandbox-container input').daterangepicker({
  opens: 'right'
});
```